# Recording System Sounds With Java

Tags: java, audio, system, record

How does one obtain the system sound, (beeps and such), and then record it and output to a sound file? I can get sound from a line - in mic, but I can't figure out how to get the actual system sound.

Any assistance?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: You cannot record the output from Java. This has been asked several times already. I don't know of any way to access the system sounds, either, though there may be a way for some platforms, and certainly with JNI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been a long unanswered question which has been frustrating me as well.

I found a way to capture/record Windows' audio output, but it is more of a hack job rather then an actual solution. [Disclaimer: This is my blog.](http://learningthroughfailure.blogspot.com/2014/08/i-have-done-something-no-one-else-has.html) I say this because from what I have found Java doesn't capture the data from a specified audio device [See the official Accessing Audio System Resources Java tutorial (although you can list out all of the audio I/O devices/audio ports, [See: Programming JavaSound](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84314/wired-for-sound/)), instead it just takes the default device (which is how I 'solved' the problem).

This, however, introduces a problem where because the default recording device is no longer the microphone, you can no longer record from the microphone as another input; Although, using the Port.Info class to capture the microphone might be a possible solution to this side effect.

I hope this will help.